# Javascript - how to change specific div background image using css and JS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to change background of a div in html using JS and css. Below is the code i tried but it's not working.

```js
function upDate(previewPic)
{
  var abc=previewPic.src;
  console.log(abc);
  x=document.getElementById('image');
  document.getElementById('1').style.backgroundImage = previewPic.src;
}
```

```css
body{
    margin: 2%;
    border: 1px solid black;
    background-color: #b3b3b3;
}
.image{
    line-height:650px;
    width: 575px;
    height: 650px;
    border:5px solid black;
    margin:0 auto;
    background-color: #8e68ff;
    background-image: url('');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    color:#FFFFFF;
    text-align: center;
    background-size: 100%;
    margin-bottom:25px;
    font-size: 150%;
}
.preview{
    width:10%;
    margin-left:17%;
    border: 10px solid black;
}
img{
    width:95%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Photo Gallery</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
  <script src = "js/gallery.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

  <div class="image" id = "1">
    Hover over an image below to display here.
  </div>

  <img class = "preview" alt = "Styling with a Bandana" src = "https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/389177/bacon.jpg" onmouseover = "upDate(this)" onmouseout = "unDo()">

  <img class = "preview" alt = "With My Boy" src = "https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/389177/bacon2.JPG" onmouseover = "upDate(this)" onmouseout = "unDo()">

  <img class = "preview" src = "https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/389177/bacon3.jpg" alt = "Young Puppy" onmouseover = "upDate(this)" onmouseout = "unDo()">

</body>
</html>
```

This is JS function which get source of image and keep it in abc variable. Later I am using it but it's not working. I can see on console the correct url.

Comment: I have tried below also but it didn't work.
document.getElementById('1').style.backgroundImage = "url('previewPic.src')";

Comment: How do you expect code to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not have the function of leaving the picture - `unDo()`.

```js
var obj;

function upDate(previewPic) {
    document.getElementById("image").innerHTML = previewPic.alt;
    document.getElementById("image").style.background = "url('" + previewPic.src + "')";
}

function unDo() {
    var oldAlt = "Hover over an image below to display here.";
    document.getElementById("image").innerHTML = oldAlt;
    document.getElementById("image").style.background = "#8e68ff";
    document.getElementById("image").style.backgroundImage = "url('')";
}
```

```css
body {
    margin: 2%;
    border: 1px solid black;
    background-color: #b3b3b3;
}

#image {
    line-height: 650px;
    width: 575px;
    height: 650px;
    border: 5px solid black;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: #8e68ff;
    background-image: url("");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    color: #ffffff;
    text-align: center;
    background-size: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
    font-size: 150%;
}

.preview {
    width: 10%;
    margin-left: 17%;
    border: 10px solid black;
}

img {
    width: 95%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <title>Photo Gallery</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/gallery.css" />
        <script src="js/gallery.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="image">
            Hover over an image below to display here.
        </div>
        <img class="preview" alt="Styling with a Bandana" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/389177/bacon.jpg" onmouseover="upDate(this)" onmouseout="unDo()" />
        <img class="preview" alt="With My Boy" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/389177/bacon2.JPG" onmouseover="upDate(this)" onmouseout="unDo()" />
        <img class="preview" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/389177/bacon3.jpg" alt="Young Puppy" onmouseover="upDate(this)" onmouseout="unDo()" />
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: thanks alot, my mistake was "url('"+previewPic.src+"')".

Answer (score 0):

Rename id name with number to text and then try again.

Comment: that's not necessary, might be reason but I checked that also. My problem was "url('"+previewPic.src+"')", thanks for your help